# Changing a users password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using [basic-auth-mongoose](https://github.com/thauburger/basic-auth-mongoose) and there doesn't seem to be any documentation in regards to changing someone password.

I attempted to do this:

```
        user.update({                                                            
             email: req.body.email,                                               
             password: req.body.password,                                                                                                                                
             claimed: true,                                                       
             username: req.body.email                                             
         }, function (err, user) {                                                
             if (err) {                                                                                                          
                 res.json(err);                                                   
             }                                                                    
             console.log("12");                                                                                                  
         });
```

Not only was `12` logged, but also in the database, the email, claimed, and username have been updated. But not the password.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: If you turn on the debug mode for mongoose what does the query that is sent to the server for the update look like?